# Uploading html and css to bluehost account but it's not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shared-hosting

I have some basic HTML/CSS/JS that i've written on my local computer. I uploaded it to my BlueHost account but sadly once it's uploaded it's not rendering correctly. For example in my code I have a button coded like this:

```
<button class="c-hamburger"><span>toggle menu</span></button>
```

but blue host renders my page like this (once I load and inspect it):

```
<p><button class="c-hamburger"><span>toggle menu</span></button></p>
```

Also my css is all off.. I'm not sure why this is happening and I'm a newbie at live hosting. Please help.

Comment: The HTML has changed because you've got a `</p>` element with no matching starting tag - hence the renderer adds one for you - although it's position is a little odd as it normally places the elements together.

Also, the CSS issues are most likely because you've not set the path correctly on the live site. If you're not already, use relative paths.

Comment: You can use the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to check for things like unmatched tags. (Even just copy/pasting into a fiddle/pen site like JSFiddle would work.) You should be able to go to Network in the Developer Tools in your browser to see if your CSS file is 404ing.

Comment: I also have a BlueHost account. This kind of issue can't be due to your host, but to your HTML which is certainly to be fixed. You can test your HTML for errors [here](https://validator.w3.org/). You can test your live link **or** paste your HTML directly.